# Ajax get 500 error sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know there have lot of duplicate questions about 500 internal error, but my case is the console "sometimes" shows the error message not always.
I'm wondering if I add too many javascript libraries in the beginning of the HTML? I add total 11 libraries files, jQuery at the first, i18n library, and the rest of 9 files. Sometimes console shows one of the file has 500 error, next time shows nothing or another library has the error message. Somebody else have the same problem?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Error occurred in server side code.

Comment: review server, where is ?, if you have access to logs review it

Comment: Thanks I'll try to access to logs. When the problem occurred, I can't even click the save button cause some of the libraries didn't GET.